# Cropping videos in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios4, crop

We can crop images. Can we crop videos?

Comment: hi, do u find any answer? I need to implement the same

Comment: @Priya, Sorry I din't get any answer. Awaiting for clue or suggestion from expert's

Comment: thank you, if I found any, I wil inform you

Comment: Thanks And I do the same once i find it.

Comment: @Anand Hi, I am late here. But did you manage to find the ways of doing this? If you do, please share, as I would like to learn. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since video is a collection of pictures you can crop all frames from video and after create new video. AVFoundation guide describe some tasks:
[Putting it all Together: Capturing Video Frames as UIImage Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW3)
After this you crops images and write video

> You can use an asset writer to produce a QuickTime movie file or an
>   MPEG-4 file from media such as sample buffers or still images.

See for more details [AV Foundation Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH1-SW3)

Comment: Thanks for answering. The link which u provided is really good. By using  CMSampleBuffer i get Images but how to convert it into video.

Comment: The link "Putting it all Together..." no longer works is there a new link, or another tutorial someone can provide

Comment: @beryllium link is not working so downvoted. no doubt about that your answer is right.

Answer (score 5):

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];
exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

CMTime start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 600);
CMTime duration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(120.0, 600);
CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeMake(start, duration);
exportSession.timeRange = range;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void){
               handler(exportSession);
               [exportSession release];}];
```

Here we get a video of first 2 mins.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using AVAssetExportSession, AVVideoComposition, and AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool (and just set up a CALayer hierarchy with the positioning you want). I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way, though.

Answer (score 0):

it's not as simple as images

but it could be as easy as the correct specification of the video but there is not enough information.

in the decoding settings, you can manipulate video pixels by geometry, ie, anamorphic, squeezed, stretched and also player/browser settings, the image window or player window, you can specify a small player window and a magnification level. if you allow or disallow zoom/magnification, you'll force an offscreeen draw or black bars.

i would encode to the correct size and platform for best quality, these kinds of fixes are 'kludges' but they work in a pinch.  i would grab the quicktime sdk and poke around.